# Docker registry server gave an error "HTTP: server gave response to HTTPS client"

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-registry

At first I have installed Docker Desktop on my windows and I haven't created any authentication for Docker Desktop but I created authentication for Docker Registry by providing username and password. This can be done by creating an authentication by using this commands:

- **mkdir auth** --> create a directory to store the authentication.
- **docker run --entrypoint htpasswd httpd:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd** (it will run a container with username and password as testuser and testpassword created in it and store the secrets in auth directory under the htpasswd file.)

Then I run the Docker registry as container using the command:

- **docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2 --> It create a registry under the port 5000**

  Now the Docker Registry was ready, and listens to the port 5000. To pull/push the image use the Docker Registry Repository URL as <IP address>(IP address of the machine where Docker Registry is running):<port>(5000)/ <image name>:<image tag>. for.eg: 192.168.2.154:5000/ubuntu:18.02

for more references use this official Documentation in Docker (https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

If we are doing the action like pull/push from/to Docker registry (or) we want to access our registry where our docker server is HTTP not HTTPS so it might show an error like http: server gave response to HTTPS client.

My config file for my Docker Desktop --> Docker Engine

```
{
"builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

when I try to pull an pre-defined base image from Docker HUB it won't ask for credentials. when we try for other images so we need to login to docker HUB and we can pull the non-base image.
Here when I try to push the image from client to our Docker Registry server. it shows an error that **http: server gave response to HTTPS client**. because The error suggests that the client is trying to connect to an HTTP server but is receiving a response indicating that it should be using HTTPS instead. This can happen when a server is configured to only accept HTTPS connections and redirects any HTTP requests to the HTTPS version of the site.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the error related to http: server gave response to HTTPS client., follow the steps below:

Open Docker Desktop and go to Settings.
Click on "Docker Engine" to access the Docker Engine configuration file.
Add the following configuration to the file:

```
{
"builder": {
"gc": {
  "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
  "enabled": true
  }
},
"experimental": false,
"features": {
"buildkit": true
},
"insecure-registries": [
    "192.168.2.154:5000"
   ]
}
```

Make sure to replace the IP address and port with the appropriate values. The IP address should be the IP address of the machine where Docker Desktop is installed, and the port should be 5000 for Docker Registry.

Save the changes to the configuration file.
Apply the changes and restart Docker Desktop. This will restart the Docker engine with the updated configuration.
If you are using Docker on Ubuntu/Linux, you can find the daemon.json file at the path "/etc/docker/daemon.json" or on Windows Server at the path "C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json". Edit the file and add the insecure-registries configuration. Afterward, restart the Docker daemon and Docker using the following commands:
{
"insecure-registries": [
"192.168.2.154:5000"
]
}

'sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker'
Once Docker is restarted, you can verify the configuration by running the command docker info. It will display the Docker configuration, including whether the insecure registry is in place and listening to the specified IP address.

To pull and push images to the insecure registry, you need to tag the image appropriately. For example:

docker tag ubuntu:18.02 192.168.2.154:5000/ubuntu:18.02
docker push 192.168.2.154:5000/ubuntu:18.02
In the above example, the image ubuntu:18.02 is tagged with the address and pushed to the Docker registry.